# URL in string being corrupted with apostrophe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I've been working on a web site that has to send an email out with a URL in it, however, the URL is being printed with a superfluous ';' in it.
For example:

> In order for us to continue with your request, please click [here](http://localhost/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=605fa142&code=7fBi8oRavW6C) to confirm your email address or paste the following link in to your browser:
>   http://localhost/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=605fa142&code;=7fBi8oRavW6C

The second instance of the URL above should not have a ';' after the 'code' parameter. You'll notice that the URL in the `<a href>here</a>` does not have the extra apostrophe.
I've tried this with IE and Chrome and get the same result. I suspect that the browser is putting the apostrophe in but I don't know why.

The email text is pulled from a resource file:

```
<p>Dear {0}<p></BR><p>Thank you for signing up to access the Extranet with the email address {1}.</p><p>In order for us to continue with your request, please click <a href="{2}">here</a> to confirm your email address or paste the following link in to your browser:</BR><a href="{2}">{2}</a>
```

and is populated with the details using `string.format()` :

```
string.Format(ConfirmEmailBody, firstName, email, callbackUrl)
```

I've been struggling with this for the last couple of hours, the only thing I can think of is that the sequence `&code=` carries some sort of significance. Has anyone else seen this before?

**EDIT 1**

The callbackUrl is generated with this code:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
               new { userId = userID, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

I've put a breakpoint in VS after the creation of callbackUrl and the url being generated *doesn't* contain an apostrophe.

**EDIT 2**

It seems that 'code' doesn't have any significance. I changed the URL parameters and the browsers print the string with superfluous apostrophes for each parameter :

```
localhost/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=80216107-1d0e-432c-88cc-69f18be2111e&foo;=wibble&bar;=wobble
```

Comment: Have you eliminated the obvious possiblity? i.e. placing a breakpoint on the `string.Format(...)` line to see if `callbackUrl` does not actually have that extra _semicolon_?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing there. The same parameter ('callbackUrl') is injected in two places with '{2}'.

Comment: Not sure if it is a copy-paste error, but there is another difference between your URLs: the one in "Here" contains another UserID (has a "2" at the end)

Comment: Show the code relevant to `callbackUrl`'s assignment/definition. My bet is on the problem being in how you're creating that URL in the first place.

Comment: @TimBourguignon - Well spotted. It is a copy and paste error, I chopped down the URL's to make it easier to read.

Comment: I guess you'd have to translate the `&` to `&amp;`, before inserting it into the raw html text - something seems to be trying to interpret `&code` as a html escape sequence.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - That's fixed it, if you write that as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush Good to hear you fixed it! Created an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something seems to be trying to interpret `&code` as a html escape sequence, and adds the semicolon to complete the sequence.

You'll have to escape the string before adding it to the raw html, changing `&` to `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from C.Evenhuis answer, I changed the string.format from :

```
string.Format(ConfirmEmailBody, FirstName, Email, callbackUrl)
```

to:

```
string.Format(ConfirmEmailBody, FirstName, Email, callbackUrl, callbackUrl.Replace("&","&amp;"))
```

The first instance of callbackUrl is used in the `<a href>` tags whilst the second instance is used for dumping on screen. It can now be cut and pasted into a browser and works fine. This doesn't answer my question as to why the web browsers are doing this, but at least it gets it working.